# Android firebase database permission denied despite the fact that a user is logged in

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've never used firebase database and I think I'm having some "newbie" problems and I just can't solve it. Getting to the point:

My database is structured like this:

```
database
 /cookbooks
    /key: cookbook id, value: CookBook.class
       /recipes

 /recipes
    /key: recipe id, value: Recipe.class
 / users
   /cookbooks
      /cookbook id
```

What I want to achieve is that on start of the app data is downloaded from those repositories (from all of them) and stored in a DataManager class.

Below are the rules in my database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "recipes-309da": {
      "cookbooks": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
    },

    "recipes": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
    },

    "users": {
      "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null",
      }
    }
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that I'm keep getting "Permission denied" notification. Data is not being downloaded nor I can save any data to the database.

I would be grateful for any help you could give me!

Some relevant code:

```
public static final String STORAGE_PATH_PHOTOS_UPLOADS = "photos_uploads/";
    public static final String DATABASE_PATH_PHOTOS_UPLOADS = "photos_uploads";
    public static final String DATABASE_PATH_RECIPES_UPLOADS = "recipes";
    public static final String DATABASE_PATH_COOKBOOKS_UPLOADS = "cookbooks";
    public static final String DATABASE_PATH_USERS = "users";

private StorageReference mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabasePhotosUploads = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ConstantsForUploads.DATABASE_PATH_PHOTOS_UPLOADS);
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRecipesUploads = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ConstantsForUploads.DATABASE_PATH_RECIPES_UPLOADS);
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseCookBooksUploads = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ConstantsForUploads.DATABASE_PATH_COOKBOOKS_UPLOADS);
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsersUploads = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ConstantsForUploads.DATABASE_PATH_USERS);

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRecipesUploadsBelowUser = mDatabaseRecipesUploads.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseCookBooksKeyUploadsInUserBooks = mDatabaseUsersUploads.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("books");
```

At start of MainActivity I use a method attachListeners(ALL) from GeneralDataManager.

```
public void attachListeners(int staticIntFromGeneralUploader) {
    // attaches and detaches SingleValueEventListeners so it can download data while opening an app
    mDatabaseRecipesUploadsBelowUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mCurrentUserRecipesList = new ArrayList<>();
            mCurrentUserRecipeTitleKeyMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Recipe recipe1 = snapshot.getValue(Recipe.class);
                mCurrentUserRecipesList.add(recipe1);
                mCurrentUserRecipeTitleKeyMap.put(recipe1.getTitle(), snapshot.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mDatabaseCookBooksUploads.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mRecipesInCookBooksMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshotOfCookBooks : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String cookBookKey1 = snapshotOfCookBooks.getKey();

                if (mCurrentUserCookBookKeyTitleMap.containsKey(cookBookKey1)) {
                    CookBook cookbook1 = snapshotOfCookBooks.getValue(CookBook.class);
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshotOfRecipesInsideCookBooks : snapshotOfCookBooks.getChildren()) {
                        if (snapshotOfRecipesInsideCookBooks.getValue() == Recipe.class) {
                            Recipe recipe1 = snapshotOfRecipesInsideCookBooks.getValue(Recipe.class);
                            if (!mRecipesInCookBooksMap.containsKey(cookbook1)) {
                                mRecipesInCookBooksMap.put(cookbook1, new ArrayList<Recipe>());
                                mRecipesInCookBooksMap.get(cookbook1).add(recipe1);
                            } else {
                                mRecipesInCookBooksMap.get(cookbook1).add(recipe1);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            for (CookBook logCookBook : mRecipesInCookBooksMap.keySet()) {
                for (Recipe logRecipe : mRecipesInCookBooksMap.get(logCookBook)) {
                    Log.e("R inside C", "CookBook " + logCookBook.getTitle() + " containts Recipe: " + logRecipe.getTitle());
                }
            }

            // attaches listener so that fragment displaying cookbooks receives arraylist containing cookbooks
            if (mRecipesInCookBooksMap != null && mRecipesUpdateListener != null) {
                mRecipesUpdateListener.onMapChanged((HashMap<CookBook, ArrayList<Recipe>>) mRecipesInCookBooksMap);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mDatabaseCookBooksKeyUploadsInUserBooks.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mCurrentUserCookBookKeyTitleMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key1 = snapshot.getKey();
                String title1 = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

                mCurrentUserCookBookKeyTitleMap.put(key1, title1);
            }
            Log.e("CurrentUserCookBook", "Updated" + mCurrentUserCookBookKeyTitleMap.keySet());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    if (staticIntFromGeneralUploader == GeneralDataManager.RECIPE_UPDATES_LISTENER) {
        mDatabaseRecipesUploadsBelowUser.addValueEventListener(recipeUpdatesListener);

    } else if (staticIntFromGeneralUploader == GeneralDataManager.COOKBOOK_UPDATES_LISTENER) {
        mDatabaseCookBooksKeyUploadsInUserBooks.addValueEventListener(cookBookKeysInUserBooksUpdatesListener);

    } else if (staticIntFromGeneralUploader == GeneralDataManager.RECIPE_IN_COOKBOOK_UPDATES_LISTENER) {
        mDatabaseCookBooksUploads.addValueEventListener(cookBookDatabaseListener);

    } else if (staticIntFromGeneralUploader == GeneralDataManager.ATTACH_ALL_LISTENERS) {
        mDatabaseRecipesUploadsBelowUser.addValueEventListener(recipeUpdatesListener);
        mDatabaseCookBooksKeyUploadsInUserBooks.addValueEventListener(cookBookKeysInUserBooksUpdatesListener);
        mDatabaseCookBooksUploads.addValueEventListener(cookBookDatabaseListener);
    }

}
```

Part of MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // new ImageLoadTask(imageUrl, mProfilePicture).execute();
    //Referring to the name of the User who has logged in currently and adding a valueChangeListener
    myFirebaseRef.child(mUid).child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        //onDataChange is called every time the name of the User changes in your Firebase Database
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Inside onDataChange we can get the data as an Object from the dataSnapshot
            //getValue returns an Object. We can specify the type by passing the type expected as a parameter
            String data = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            GeneralDataManager.getInstance().attachListeners(GeneralDataManager.ATTACH_ALL_LISTENERS);
        }

        //onCancelled is called in case of any error
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mAuth.signOut();
        }
    });

}
```

And part of the log:

```
10-09 22:13:10.971 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/AndroidBash: **signIn:radzikjasiek@gmail.com**
10-09 22:13:11.061 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.085 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.110 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.124 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.146 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.168 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.296 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.481 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.498 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.843 27271-27283/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( Z7aaBQR6GRMaQ35N22jQg2PRgau2 ).
10-09 22:13:11.843 27271-27283/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( Z7aaBQR6GRMaQ35N22jQg2PRgau2 ).
10-09 22:13:11.874 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
10-09 22:13:11.875 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
10-09 22:13:11.875 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/AndroidBash: **onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:Z7aaBQR6GRMaQ35N22jQg2PRgau2**
10-09 22:13:11.875 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/AndroidBash: signInWithEmail:onComplete:true
10-09 22:13:11.901 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:11.903 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9d2abf00
10-09 22:13:11.914 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 11492
10-09 22:13:11.915 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Using measurement service
10-09 22:13:11.915 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Connecting to remote service
10-09 22:13:11.926 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Activity paused, time: 14198714
10-09 22:13:11.930 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=11492, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2359265460650245341}]
10-09 22:13:11.970 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: onActivityCreated
10-09 22:13:11.980 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
10-09 22:13:11.984 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Using measurement service
10-09 22:13:11.985 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
10-09 22:13:12.077 27271-28499/com.example.radzik.recipes I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
10-09 22:13:12.077 27271-28499/com.example.radzik.recipes I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
10-09 22:13:12.297 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.svox.pico
10-09 22:13:12.307 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Using measurement service
10-09 22:13:12.307 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
10-09 22:13:12.309 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=LoginActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-2359265460650245341, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2359265460650245340}]
10-09 22:13:12.318 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.svox.pico/com.svox.pico.PicoService}
10-09 22:13:12.319 27271-27354/com.example.radzik.recipes I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.svox.pico/com.svox.pico.PicoService}
10-09 22:13:12.324 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Using measurement service
10-09 22:13:12.324 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
10-09 22:13:12.324 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 14199108
10-09 22:13:12.383 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:12.478 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FA: Connected to remote service
10-09 22:13:12.478 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
10-09 22:13:12.491 27271-27370/com.example.radzik.recipes W/SyncTree: Listen at /users/Z7aaBQR6GRMaQ35N22jQg2PRgau2/name failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied
10-09 22:13:12.540 27271-27281/com.example.radzik.recipes I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7207(410KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(136KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 54MB/58MB, paused 16.082ms total 68.851ms
10-09 22:13:12.637 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
10-09 22:13:12.791 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FirebaseAuth: **Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.**
10-09 22:13:12.791 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
10-09 22:13:12.903 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
10-09 22:13:12.904 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
10-09 22:13:12.904 27271-27271/com.example.radzik.recipes D/AndroidBash: **onAuthStateChanged:signed_out**
10-09 22:13:12.905 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9d2ac5e0
10-09 22:13:13.146 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:13.178 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes V/RenderScript: 0xa2702000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
10-09 22:13:13.215 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2f56080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb40ad170)
10-09 22:13:13.450 27271-28499/com.example.radzik.recipes W/SyncTree: Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
10-09 22:13:13.470 27271-28499/com.example.radzik.recipes W/SyncTree: Listen at /recipes failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
10-09 22:13:13.478 27271-28499/com.example.radzik.recipes W/SyncTree: Listen at /photos_uploads failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
10-09 22:13:13.486 27271-28499/com.example.radzik.recipes W/SyncTree: Listen at /cookbooks failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
10-09 22:13:13.594 27271-28499/com.example.radzik.recipes W/SyncTree: Listen at /users/Z7aaBQR6GRMaQ35N22jQg2PRgau2/books failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
10-09 22:13:13.613 27271-28499/com.example.radzik.recipes W/SyncTree: Listen at /recipes/Z7aaBQR6GRMaQ35N22jQg2PRgau2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
10-09 22:13:16.296 27271-27385/com.example.radzik.recipes E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9d2ac4a0
10-09 22:13:17.557 27271-27940/com.example.radzik.recipes V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Did you enable the sign in method in firebase console, or added INTERNET permission in manifest? Can you post the relevant code and logs too?

Comment: Yep, I have INTERNET permission. Just uploaded part of the log and some code

Comment: Try applying `".read": true,".write": true` rules and check if there is no problem with rules. By the way it's not a **newbie problem**. You've begun your firebase journey with complex data structure.

Comment: I already tested database upload and download and it works just fine. All the operations such as deleting recipes form cookbooks etc. are working too. The problem starts after "closing" access to users only.

Comment: In the log i found out that the user signs in and immediately signs out... Have no idea why

Comment: Check removing all  'mAuth.signOut();' from listeners. And if that's the issue do it manually i.e. when user press sign out button of something like that.

Comment: And, can you please tell me where `myFirebaseRef`, in `MainActivity`'s `onStart` method is pointing to?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a solution elsewhere, precisely in rules in my database. I posted a full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked deeper into the problem and found the solution this morning. It's quite easy and I have no idea why I haven't came up with it earlier.

The problem was with the rules.

These are old rules:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "recipes-309da": {
      "cookbooks": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
    },

    "recipes": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
    },

    "users": {
      "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null",
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Method I used to create user was:

```
mRef.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
```

The result was obvious - access to /users was restricted to users, thus no user could effectively sign in to database...

I changed it and now it works perfectly fine. Below I put new, updated code. Great thanks for all help you provided me with.

```
{
  "rules": {
        "users": {
                "$uid": {
                    ".read": true,
                            ".write": true,

                    "books": {
                                ".read": "auth != null",
                        ".write": "auth != null",
                }
            } 
         },

        "recipes": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null",
          }   
        },

                "cookbooks": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth != null",
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Accept it as an answer so that it can help the users with similar issues in the future.

Comment: I get an error "You can accept your own answer tomorrow". Tommorow it is then :)